# Screen and resolution issues

Tags: monitor

The maximum resolution for this monitor is 640x480
It seems that the display does not match the resolution
How do I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` for editing, e. g.:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Change these settings:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1024x768-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
   GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
   ```

   and add this setting:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=640x480
   ```
3. Update the Grub configuration (`sudo update-grub`) and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

#### A GUI approach

1. Press Super key and type setting in the dashboard
2. Select system setting and then select display
3. Change screen resolution of your choice